# Programmatically set a cell's value to the current date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a string to input today's date "= Now()" on Excel's A row each time i run the macro below.

```
Set NextRow = Sheet1.Range("B:N").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

Sheet1.Range("B310:N310", "B311:N311").Copy
Sheet1.Activate
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set NextRow = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without vouching for your code, I believe you want to add a time stamp in column A on NextRow and the row below. If so, then after your PasteSpecial line, add:

```
NextRow.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(2).Value = Now
```

You can format the whole column A so the time stamp displays the way you like.

Comment: This is great, it works but i need it to apply to two or more rows and that line only copies the current date on one row, can you please help me with that too? :D

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. I assume you want the time stamp on both pasted rows.

Comment: Thank you so much <3